# Deserialize class without default constructor Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class that contains a `List<Pair<String,String>>.` Where pair is Javafx.util.pair

It can serialize just fine, but when Jackson tries to deserialize, It throws  the following exception

> Cannot construct instance of `javafx.util.Pair` (no Creators, like
>   default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no
>   delegate- or property-based Creator)

I know i could subclass pair and give it a default constructor, but is there a cleaner way to do this with Jackson? Or maybe I should look at another library for serialization?

Comment: The cleanest way I can think of is using Jackson's MixIn Annontations. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations At least it sounds like a standard use case. Quote: "Mix-in" annotations are a way to associate annotations with classes, without modifying (target) classes themselves, originally intended to help support 3rd party datatypes where user can not modify sources to add annotations.